# React Check if Const is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello i am new to react and i have a problem..
I want to set a Error Message and check if its empty.

This is my code:

```
const [errormsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");


const register = (e) =>{

    if(firstname === "" || lastname === ""){
            setErrorMsg("Please fill out all Gaps!");
            e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(errormsg === ""){
    //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

But everytime it skips the part where it should stop. Because even if lastname is empty it continues but i dont know why because it should stop there.

I also added the line e.preventDefault(); because i want to show the error message to the user and if it reloads after every submit this does not work

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should be called above the first if condition

Comment: Okay thanks but it even if the error message is not "" it just executes the command under the second if statment

Answer (score 1):

React state is a kind of asynchronous, you cannot expect next line have state set, so what you should do is

```js
const [errormsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");


const register = (e) =>{

    if(firstname === "" || lastname === ""){
            setErrorMsg("Please fill out all Gaps!");
            e.preventDefault();
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
  if(errormsg === ""){
    //DO SOMETHING
   }
}, [errormsg])
```

the callback in useEffect will execute every time `errormsg` change.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-surf-sv0ej?file=/src/App.js